# Where to find the settings about disabled built-in extensions in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I usually disable some built-in extensions in VS Code that I do not use, I use [Code Setting Sync](https://github.com/shanalikhan/code-settings-sync) extension to sync my VS Code settings.

But it does not sync my settings about disabled built-in extensions, I suppose that extension ignores the file that contain those settings. So I am thinking about adding it manually as describe [here](https://github.com/shanalikhan/code-settings-sync/wiki/Custom-Sync). But I was not able to find that file which stores those settings.

So where can I find that setting file?